# Change a value of element in an ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a situation where I am looping over a group of objects and for each object I have a button that when clicked should toggle a variable of `isActive` to true, but I want this to be specific to just that one element in the loop, currently I can only get it to make all elements active as `isActive` is component variable.

I created a plunkr in the hope it might help https://plnkr.co/edit/biOfbIjMxjOMUMFWOgyY?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of introducing a class member to hold the state for each item, you can hold it bound to the item itself. Change the template as following:

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{'is-active': item.isActive}">
      <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
      <button (click)="item.isActive = !item.isActive">Toggle active</button>

      <div class="active" *ngIf="item.isActive">
        <small>This should show for only this object in the loop</small>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

No additional setup is required.

Comment: That was perfect, thanks! I updated the plunkr for anyone who wants to see working example https://plnkr.co/edit/biOfbIjMxjOMUMFWOgyY?p=preview

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this an example of `MVVM` ? For example, I had a similar problem where my Model contained some data and then for my ViewModel, I added an extra variable to keep track of the state and bind to the item in question